Error with a python recursively user-defined type
I am using the recursively defined type "Json" type as suggested in this answer to this SO question.
However I am running into unexpected errors as shown in the code below. The first assignment passes but the other three fail. I would expect them to either all pass or all fail. (Preferably, pass).
Is it a bug? If it is a bug is there a workaround without adding unnecessary test to the definitions of JsonType and JsonValue?
import typing as t

JsonType: t.TypeAlias = t.List['JsonValue'] | t.Mapping[str, 'JsonValue']
JsonValue: t.TypeAlias = str | int | float | None | JsonType


v0 = [0., 0.] # (variable) v0: list[float]
v1 = [0.] * 2 # (variable) v1: list[float]

test01: JsonType = {
  "v0": [0., 0.] # ok
}

test02: JsonType = {
  "v0": v0 # error
}

test11: JsonType = {
  "v": [0.] * 2 # error
}

test12: JsonType = {
  "v": v2 # error
}

Expression of type "dict[str, list[float]]" is incompatible with declared type "RJsonableType"
Type "dict[str, list[float]]" is incompatible with type "RJsonableType"
  "dict[str, list[float]]" is incompatible with "List[RJsonableValue]"
  "dict[str, list[float]]" is incompatible with "Mapping[str, RJsonableValue]"
    Type parameter "_VT_co@Mapping" is covariant, but "list[float]" is not a subtype of "RJsonableValue"
      Type "list[float]" is incompatible with type "RJsonableValue"
        "list[float]" is incompatible with "str"
        "list[float]" is incompatible with "int"
        "list[float]" is incompatible with "float"
...PylancereportAssignmentType


You never assign v2.

What is RJsonableType?

This is a classical question. Two reasons: list[] is invariant, and v0/[0.] * 2, being of inferred type list[float], are not assignable to list[JsonValue]. Explicit hints help: v0: list[JsonValue] = [0.] * 2 (indirect link, original link too long). I'll find a dupe.

As for the third test, you could try filing an issue at @microsoft/pyright, though I'm not sure if that's an intentional design choice or not.

I could only find this: Why does Mypy report a subset of JSON as invalid?. There are likely better dupe targets, however.
